# passing function calls a method argument java

Tags: java, lambda

I am new to Java 8 and trying to optimize some of my code using lambda, functional interface.

My demo method:

```
private SampleReturn getExecRequest() {
    //some code       
    SampleReturn sample = cache.get("exec key");
    return sample;
}
```

Now this method is called and if return value is not null then some other methods are called. This piece is 2-3 places. E.g:

```
SampleReturn sample = getExecRequest();
if (sample != null && sample.valid()) {
    saveRecords(records);
    insertMessages(messageId, Subject, Sender);
}
```

Another usage:

```
SampleReturn sample = getExecRequest();
if (sample != null && sample.valid()) {
    saveRecords(records);
    saveSamples(records);
}
```

Based on the output of sample, I am calling some different functions but pattern is repeating. I wanted to understand if I could use any java 8 functional interface and optimize this piece where I could pass in the code to be executed directly to `getExecRequest()` and that method can check the conditions and then call other functions if required.

Comment: Sure, just pass it as a Consumer.

Comment: Can you please explain me how to do that? I tried looking up some documents but everywhere the only examples I could find was using System.out.printlns and printing them out.

Comment: What's the relationship between `sample` and `records`? Is there any?

Comment: No relationship, sample is just an object containing criteria if downstream code should be executed or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a `Runnable` to the method and execute it conditionally:

```
private void doExecRequest(Runnable callback) {
    //some code       
    SampleReturn sample = cache.get("exec key");
    if (sample != null && sample.valid()) {
        callback.run();
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
doExecRequest(() -> {
    saveRecords(records);
    insertMessages(messageId, Subject, Sender);
});
```

Or:

```
doExecRequest(() -> {
    saveRecords(records);
    saveSamples(records);
});
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that. You earlier mentioned about `consumer`. What's the difference between the two? and why I can't or shouldn't use `consumer` here?

Comment: `Consumer` takes an input parameter. I suggested it because I mistakenly thought `records` was produced by the method.